# How does concatenation work in C?

Tags: java, c, string, concatenation

I am currently taking a course on C at school, After getting too used to Java, I don't seem to understand how concatenation is being done in C. A search in Google doesn't help matters as most of the code I saw was on how to concatenate actual strings like `"Hello" + "World"` .

In Java, Say I wanted to concatenate an arithmetic expression in a line, I could easily just use the `+` operator, but in C, the only place I get to see something familiar is in something like this:

```
int grade;
scanf("%d", &grade);
```

I can understand that the `grade` variable is being taken in as input, but if I wanted to perform an arithmetic operation with this variable using the `+` or the `&` operators, I get errors. Here's an example of what I tried doing:

```
printf("The average score is "& grade / 2 & "");
```

Which returns an error even when I use the `+` operator, but works fine in Java:

```
System.out.println("The average score is " + grade / 2 + "");
```

I can understand that they are different languages but aren't the `+` and the `&` operators supposed to be used for concatenation in C also?

Comment: read up on the concept of C format strings, it looks like that's what's confusing you ?

Comment: In C, there's no 'String' type, only arrays of bytes interpreted as characters. End of 'string' is designated by zero byte. Thus, whenever you want to 'concatenate strings', you 'concatenate' two byte arrays. This can be done by explicitly allocating new memory chunk of sufficient capacity and moving contents of source arrays there. And explicitly free()ing source arrays, if needed.

Answer (score 4):

No. The + and the & are not for concatenation in C. Anyway, in C you would normally use [`strncat`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strncat) for concatenating `char *`(s) but your question seems to be about printing. For that, you should do something like

```
printf("The average score is %d\n", grade / 2);
```

Comment: Thanks Elliott, what if I've got other parts of the string to add to the output do I still use the `,` symbol? like `printf("The average score is %d\n", grade / 2 , " ..Good grade!" );`

Comment: You also need to use the correct [format string](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf_format_string#1970s:_C.2C_Lisp), that second one would be `printf("The average score is %d %s\n", grade / 2 , " ..Good grade!");` Note the "%s" in the format string.

Comment: @geek.x The numbers of arguments to printf after the format string should match the number of format specifiers in the format string (in most simple cases anyway). So if you want to add an additional string argument, you need to add a `%s` to your format string. However you could just add your string to the format string directly (`printf("... is %d.\n ... good grade!\n", grade / 2);`), which would make more sense.

Answer (score 2):

In java `+` sign is used to concatenate strings for eg:

```
             System.out.println("hello"+","+" "+"World");
```

Its just a rough way to show a string concatenation. This very principal is possible in java because the `+` operator is used for arthematics operation and along with that `+` is overloaded to concatenate the strings . 
 
 But in C `+` sign is supposed to perform only arthematics and not overloaded to concatenate.

So, on C the best way to print output is by using a formatted print statement: printf

`printf("String <format specifier>",arg1,arg2,...);`
for more detail on Print statement. [Click Here](http://www.codingunit.com/printf-format-specifiers-format-conversions-and-formatted-output)

Answer (score 2):

So, you have two questions disguised as a single question.

C's formatted I/O routines (`printf` and `fprintf`) don't work like Java's I/O routines at all. Instead of concatenating items to a string, you use a *format string* that has placeholders for the variable data, and then pass the variable data as additional arguments:

```
printf( "The average score is %d\n", grade/2 );
```

The `%d` is a *conversion specifier*; it tells `printf` that there is an additional argument has type `int`, and that it should be formatted as a sequence of digits.  Note that `printf` relies on the conversion specifiers in the format string to tell it how many and what types of additional arguments to expect; if you pass an argument that's the wrong type for the given conversion specifier, or don't pass enough arguments, then you will get anything from garbled output to an outright crash.  If you pass more arguments than the format string calls for, then the additional arguments are evaluated, but otherwise ignored.

Refer to your handy C reference manual for a description of all the different conversion specifiers and how they're used.

As for string concatenation, C doesn't have a string type *per se*, nor does it have a string concatenation operator<sup>1</sup>.  In C, a "string" is a sequence of character values terminated by a 0-valued byte.  Strings are *stored* as arrays of `char`, such as:

```
char h[] = "hello";
char w[] = "world";
```

The array `h` contains the values `{'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', 0}`, and `w` contains `{'w', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd', 0}`.  To concanate the strings together, you need to set aside a target buffer that's large enough to hold both strings.  If you have a compiler that supports variable-length arrays, you can do:

```
char result[ strlen(h) + strlen(w) + 2 ];
```

otherwise you'll have to allocate the memory dynamically:

```
char *result = malloc( sizeof *result * (strlen(h) + strlen(w) + 2) );
```

The `+ 2` is necessary for the space between "hello" and "world" and the terminating 0 byte.

Once you have the target buffer, you can use a combination of `strcpy` and `strcat` to write to it:

```
strcpy( result, h );
strcat( result, " " ); // note " " instead of ' '; the second argument *must* be a string
strcat( result, w );
```

or you can use `sprintf` (which works like `printf`, but writes the result to an array of `char` instead of a stream):

```
sprintf( result, "%s %s", h, w );
```

For `strcat` to work, there must already be a valid, 0-terminated string in the target buffer, which is why we started with `strcpy`, which will append a 0 byte to the end of the copied string.  An empty string contains a single 0-valued byte, so we can also do something like:

```
result[0] = 0;       // or memset( result, 0, sizeof result ), which sets the whole buffer to 0
strcat( result, h );
strcat( result, " " );
strcat( result, w );
```

`strcat` looks for the terminating 0 byte, and overwrites it with the start of the next string, then appends a 0 byte to the end of the result.

---

<sup>1. String *literals* that appear next to each other are concatenated during the preprocessing phase of compilation, so you can write something like `printf( "start of string " A_STRING_MACRO " end of string\n");`, and after preprocessing it will look like `printf( "start of string whatever was in the macro end of string\n" ), but there's no runtime concatenation operator.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

In your example

```
printf("The average score is "& grade / 2 & "");
```

the `&` operator is used to get the memory address of any variable, so when you are trying to print just a normal int variable, that `&` is not required.

you can do something like this

```
printf("The average score is %d", ( grade/2 ));
```

the `%d` used in printf is used to match the the variable that you have provided

Comment: `&` is used in an infix position here, so it doesn't take anything's address - it's the bit-wise and operator.

Comment: @sepp2k: by the way he asked the question, i thought he was getting confused with `&` in `scanf` and `printf`

Comment: Your printf has a typo ;)

Comment: @NicolasCharvozKurzawa: where... :p ;)

Answer (score 0):

You have concept of java,but all the language are not same in syntax, so my suggestion is to you is first read C language input output operation,In C language & is  used to get  the memory address of a variable,so you can not use it to con-cat two string type work,in java '+'can be used to con-cat two string it is high level language,so you can do this,but in c it is not possible,%d is used in c to get variable from memory.
So your output code will be:

`printf("the average score is %d",(grade)/2);